# Для чего нужны progress bar'ы?

Tags: html, css

Нашел в интернете много примеров прогресс баров на ксс. Но как бы я не ломал голову, я не могу представить ни одного способа их использования на сайте. Подскажите, для чего они могут понадобиться?

Comment: Для отображения прогресса в загрузке файла на сервер, например

Comment: обычно при такой процедуре вверху браузера идет полоска загрузки вроде бы. то есть по сути ее можно таким образом продублировать на сайт?

Comment: Во-первых, такое далеко не во всех браузерах, во вторых, в случае использования AJAX такого вообще нет, и нарисованный CSS прогресс-бар на сайте окажется единственным

Comment: @PaulWall если идет `ajax` запрос - то такая загрузка отображается на браузере.

Comment: в каком это браузере отображается?

Comment: _обычно при такой процедуре вверху браузера идет полоска загрузки вроде бы..._ Не путайте загрузку "с" (download), и загрузку "на" (upload). Последнее обычно не отображается стандартным интерфейсом браузера, если конечно речь не идет о инструментах разработчика.

Comment: А вообще примеров полно и без AJAX и загрузки файлов. Самый очевидный: показ текущего состояния/положения при выполнении последовательности действий (регистрация, тест, опросник и т.д. и т.п.), во всех этих случаях прогресс-бар вполне себе актуален даже без AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прогресс бар нужен для показа пользователю процесс обработки, загрузки. Также существует гифки с прелоудерами. Пользователю нравится оставаться на одной странице, в конкретном положении страницы.

Файл загружается на сервер, показываешь его. Загружаешь товара категории, показаываешь, мол обождите немного, сейчас покажу.